# TinyMCE custom formatting for pre

Tags: tinymce

I have looked everywhere and I can't figure out how to add another option to tinyMCE's drop-down for formatting. I would like to duplicate and modify the formatting for the pre tag to also give it a class of .prettyprint so that I can quickly add code snippets to my posts.

It should be technically possible, but how and which file should I amend. Alternatively can I add a button that applies this formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add something like the following ([style_fomats setting)](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3astyle_formats) to your tinymce init function in order to add a new option to the styles dropdown. Be aware that the class to be applied should be made available using [the content_css configuration setting](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css)

```
    style_formats: [{
        title: 'block styles'
    }, {
        title: 'Name_to_be_displayed',
        block: 'p',
        classes: 'class_to_be_applied', 
        exact: true
    }, {
        title: 'inline styles'
    }, {
        title: 'Red text',
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'red',
        exact: true
    }, {
        title: 'Pre formatting',
        inline: 'pre',
        classes: 'xyzpre',
        exact: true
    }],
```

> Alternatively can I add a button that
>   applies this formatting

Yes, you will need to [write your own plugin,](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) which is not that difficult.